# Is it good practice to cache parts of a 2D drawing?

Tags: java, frame-rate

I'm making a 2D game in Java and one of the main issues causing low FPS (on my slow laptop) is having to re-draw complex structures to a Graphics instance, such as dials with markings.

The dial and its markings will never change unless the window is resized, so I thought it would be a good idea to draw to a `BufferedImage` and just re-draw the image rather than re-drawing the details. The position of the needle obviously changes, so this can just be drawn on top.

I've never heard about this being done to improve the FPS of 2D games so I'm wondering if it's actually good practice to store a cache of images or if there's a better way to solve this sort of problem? Are there any issues associated with this that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching images isn't a bad idea: you can rely on raster rendering to be pretty well optimised on most any platform. In my experience (which is admittedly mostly on mobile devices where 2D graphics are concerned) the `Graphics.drawXXX()` methods are often considerably slower than `Graphics.drawImage()`.

In my experience the vast majority of 2D games out there make use of sprites (i.e. images) for rendering just about everything. Often that's true even when the graphics look like they are rendered using primitives!

Another useful technique to think about is not redrawing regions at all unless you really need to!

EDIT:

As others have mentioned, the major tradeoff is that you're going to be using more memory. You're also going to have to make sure you free up those images once you no longer need them.

Comment: Rendering in sprites is often faster because the CPU loads the entire sprite into graphics card memory.  Subsequent calls then reference the already loaded on-graphics-card memory.  In contrast, a number of drawXXX() commands typically are not stored into graphics card memory, so the CPU must execute them one at a time, leading to lots of PCI bus communication.  Some libraries support "drawing lists" where multiple drawXXX(...) commands can be loaded into graphics card memory and called as a single routine; although I haven't messed with that in a long time.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Nice background info, +1

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good practice to cache parts of a 2D drawing?

You're making a trade-off between drawing speed and storage space.  Only you can determine which is more important.

You might consider rendering your dials in advance and saving the images as GIF, JPG, or PNG files.  You would have to scale these images to your window size before you draw them.

Are you using double buffering for your Graphics panel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a good practice, and it's done all the time. Drawing to an image first before displaying it on the screen is called double buffering, and that method can be used in different ways according to the needs of the program.

The downside of double buffering is memory, since it takes more memory to store the second image, but that sounds like a trade-off you'll need to make.

Comment: I've only ever heard 'double buffering' referring to buffering the entire screen (or app window). Wikipedia seems to agree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics